# Handling constraints are not met while worker is running

Tags: constraints, task, android-workmanager

I have a WIFI (`NetworkType.UNMETERED`) constraint set on my `Worker`.

The `Worker` is uploading a heavy file to my server. It is busy waiting on an async upload task. (using `Tasks.await(task)`) After it finishes uploading, my Worker should return `Result.success()`.

I have tried testing what happens when the WIFI constraint becomes unmet while the `Worker` is busy waiting on my upload task.

So, first it looks like the `onStopped()` method is called as expected. And then, there is like a 2 seconds delay, until the `Worker` proceeds the `Tasks.await` statement (as it failed). Afterwards, I tried checking if `isStopped()` and if true, I should return a `Result.retry()`. 
So I expect, that when the WIFI is back, it should start-over my Worker, preferably immediately, but it never happens, so I'm pretty much stuck here.

What is exactly the flow of when one of the constraints of my running `Worker`, becomes unmet?